# Meaning in context of chance

Tags: meaning-in-context

What chance means in this context? By accident?

> Quirk - a strange chance occurrence

Comment: An accident is usually something bad, but _chance_ can be lucky or unlucky.

Answer (score 1):

'chance' in this context refers to a degree of probability that any random unplanned event has. It's not arranged or decided - it's simply what happens from moment to moment.

You might hear this usage in the phrase `a chance encounter`. For example:

> A woman dropped some money without noticing. I picked it up and chased after her to return it. She thanked me and we got talking. We arranged a dinner date and ended up getting married 6 months later. It's amazing what **a chance encounter** can lead to.